# Where can I get the images data set of skin diseases?

Tags: data-request, medical, disease

I want to search on images of skin diseases corpus. I need this dataset to index images in my search engine. Please suggest me how and from where i can get those images.

Answer (score 2):

We have made available some publicly accessible skin diseases images collections here: https://datasn.io/p/528

The APIs are all open. No registration required:

1. http://n3.datasn.io/data/api/v1/n3zm/image_of_skin_disease_dermatology_1/main/list/?app=html-bunker
2. http://n3.datasn.io/data/api/v1/n3zm/image_of_skin_disease_4/main/list/?app=html-bunker
3. http://n3.datasn.io/data/api/v1/n3_chennan/skin_disease_3/main/list/?app=html-bunker
4. http://n3.datasn.io/data/api/v1/n3zm/image_of_skin_disease_5/main/list/?app=html-bunker
5. http://n3.datasn.io/data/api/v1/n3_chennan/skin_disease_7/main/list/?app=html-bunker
6. http://n3.datasn.io/data/api/v1/n3zm/image_of_skin_disease_3/main/list/?app=html-bunker
7. http://n3.datasn.io/data/api/v1/n3_chennan/skin_disease_1/main/list/?app=html-bunker
8. http://n3.datasn.io/data/api/v1/n3_chennan/skin_disease_4/main/list/?app=html-bunker
9. http://n3.datasn.io/data/api/v1/n3_chennan/skin_disease_6/main/list/?app=html-bunker

Answer (score 0):

Wikimedia Commons has a few images: Start from the top category here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Diseases_and_disorders_of_the_skin

An API is available here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php

The files are quite heterogeneous. Some are drawings. I suspect they are not optimal, e.g., for training a machine learning classifier.

Besides the category system, the skin disease image files on Wikimedia Commons may also be identified with Wikidata through the Wikidata Query Service at https://query.wikidata.org, for instance, with the following SPARQL query:

```
#defaultView:ImageGrid
SELECT ?disease ?diseaseLabel ?image WHERE {
  ?disease wdt:P279+ wd:Q949302 ; wdt:P18 ?image .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

The result is available at this link: http://tinyurl.com/ya3ogyq7

However, this query only identifies 75 images.

Answer (score 0):

ISIC (International Skin Imaging Collaboration) - but with a focus on **melanoma**

https://isic-archive.com/

> ISIC has developed and is expanding an open source public access archive (ISIC Archive) of skin images to test and validate the proposed standards. This archive serves as a public resource of images for teaching and for the development and testing of automated diagnostic systems.

[Image browser](https://isic-archive.com/#images)

[API](https://isic-archive.com/api/v1)