# Data about dermatology (images + symptoms)

Tags: data-request, medical, disease

[This question is a lot similar to mine](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7255/where-can-i-get-the-images-data-set-of-skin-diseases). Sadly I am not allowed to open a bounty, and there's no answer, so I am forced to ask again. I want images, names and sympoms of Skin diseases, 100 images would do for a start, or less. The more the better of course but for a prototype, I don't really care.

And it can be paid, I contacted many dermatology websites that have a database of skin diseases, they refuse to give me dump for commercial use, no matter what I might pay.

I'm looking for free data, for small scale testing and I I want big data, many images when it's time to lunch and I'm ready to pay for it.

Images should be, skin diseases, all skin colors, all ages, all genders, many locations on the body.